# How to draw a dynamic line graph using json data?

Tags: json, graph

So basically i'm trying to draw a multi line graph from the results of microsoft emotion api result data.

`anger: 0.00108685507
contempt: 0.00179950753
disgust: 0.0000793820145
fear: 0.00272498373
happiness: 0.0000412895
neutral: 0.9678982
sadness: 0.0132255116
surprise: 0.0131443078`

This is the result data.So what i want is to have a line drawn each time a result is obtained.And the line should be drawn from a combination of these results.Each line should be drawn from 4 points as the results have 8 fields which can be paired up into 4 points.

Comment: Can anyone please guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: in javascript? maybe use a Canvas and draw something there?

Comment: Yes in javascript.

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/dwahlin/zP3mn/ This shows how you can use a Canvas and draw lines.